# On Rotating Secret through Secret console on lambda Testing getting following error:

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk, aws-secrets-manager, aws-devops

Passing  parameters for testing lambda

```
{
"SecretId":"myarn",
"ClientRequestToken":"bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb",
"Step":"testSecret"}
```

used lambda function :https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-secrets-manager-rotation-lambdas/blob/master/SecretsManagerRotationTemplate/lambda_function.py

Error:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Secret version bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb has no stage for rotation of secret arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-#:#####:secret:########3.",
  "errorType": "ValueError",
  "requestId": "##############",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 27, in lambda_handler\n    raise ValueError(\"Secret version %s has no stage for rotation of secret %s.\" % (token, arn))\n"
  ]
}
```

```
Function Logs
START RequestId: ####### Version: $LATEST
[ERROR] 2021-11-13T07:36:07.927Z ####   Secret version bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb has no stage for rotation of secret arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-#:######:secret:###.
[ERROR] ValueError: Secret version bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb has no stage for rotation of secret arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-#:#########:secret:#####.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 27, in lambda_handler
    raise ValueError("Secret version %s has no stage for rotation of secret %s." % (token, arn)
```

Comment: How are you triggering the function? Secrets Manager is the one that needs to trigger it, you can't trigger it manually.

Answer (score 1):

Your ClientRequestToken value is expired i.e. your current version id or password is expired, due to secret rotation. Try AWSCURRENT or AWSPENDING secrets.